# поиск и замена подстроки

Tags: java, строки

Можно ли в Java найти `N` количество (вводимым пользователем) вхождение под строки, и заменить лишь его если он есть, а не менять весь текст.

Допустим ввели строку `pppooopppooocccpppbb`, ищем внутри значение `ооо` и меняем его на `ddd`, а пока что программа меняет весь текст на `ooo`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Введите текст: ");
     String s = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Введенный текст: "+s);      
     System.out.print("Введите искомую строку: ");
     String str1 = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Введите заменяющую строку: ");
     String str2 = scan.nextLine();
     s=s.replaceAll(str1, str2);
     System.out.println(s);

}
```

Comment: вопрос непонятен. у тебя программа меняет вхождение, что не так тогда? что ты хочешь получить ?

Comment: @Nosferaty, a зачем вы используете `replaceAll` (All, смекаете), если вам нужно одно вхождение поменять?

Comment: @ArchDemon, проблема в том, что просто с replace, она работает так же

Comment: @Nosferaty придется свой метод писать тогда

Comment: Данный код по Вашему примеру у меня выводит `pppdddpppdddcccpppbb`, это и ожидалось? Добавьте результат, которых хотите увидеть.

Comment: @MrFylypenko ожидалось, что результат будет    `pppooopppdddcccppbb` пока что он меняет все вхождения, а нужно что бы он менял лишь одно и не важно, где оно будет стоять в конце или в середине

Comment: Может будете использовать метод `replaceFirst` вместо `replaceAll`?

Comment: @MrFylypenko а зачем, для "вытаскивания" первого и последнего совпадения можно было бы использовать indexOf(); проблема то как раз в том, что бы поменять лишь одну ту которая в середине, я думаю, что ArchDemon дело говорит по поводу написания своего метода

Comment: Да, придется написать свой метод, под логику Вашего приложения, Вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Меняем `reaplceAll` на `replaceFirst`.